# Is there any way to add a (scroll) event in ng-multi-selectdropdown which is a npm package

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**Requirement** : I want to add a scroll event in the below html code which should fire on scroll of that div,I am unable to add a scroll event which will fire on scrolling the elements

```html
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]=""  (scroll)="scrollHandler($event) [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings"(onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Here [data] ="dropdownList" consists of api response data So api response is huge array of objects I am trying to implement pagination onscroll Is there any best approach suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewChild` to get `elementRef` and register `scroll` event handler on scrolling container element. For exmaple:

```
@ViewChild(Component, { read: ElementRef, static: true }) dropdown: ElementRef

ngOnInit() {
  const dropdownRef = this.dropdown.nativeElement;
  const scrollingContainerRef = dropdownRef.querySelector('selector');

  scrollingContainerRef.addEventListener('scroll', event => {});
}
```